# Find the differential equation for the rate of charge in an electric circuit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to find Q(t) from this equation:

$\frac{dQ}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C} = V$

here is my writing:

[image]

The problem is based on the solution manual, the answer should be:

$()=(1−^{-/})$

Where is my mistake then?

Answer (score 3):

In the integration you missed a sign,
$$
\int\frac{dx}{a-x}=-\ln|a-x|+K.
$$
The reference solution apparently has an initial condition $Q(0)=0$, which would fix the integration constant $K$.

Comment: Yes the initial condition is $Q(0)=0$, the problem is now I don't understand at this stage $\frac{dQ}{CV-Q} = \frac{dt}{RC}$ will become $\ln|CV-Q| = \frac{t}{RC}+K$ but then taking the absolute value out, why we choose negative sign thus $ln(CV-Q) = \frac{t}{RC} + K$, we will get $K=CV$ eventually, but I need more explanation why we choose negative sign..

Comment: At this point you do not chose a negative sign, it was always there in the integration of $\frac{1}{a-x}=-\frac{1}{x-a}$. The inner absolute value gets resolved to fit the signs at the initial point.